# Version Control for Excel

Tags: excel, versioning

I'm currently writing my master dissertation about version control in Ms Excel and would love to understand the problem more thoroughly. Does anyone face the problem and would be willing to discuss this in a 10min zoom call? Will hopefully be able to provide the solution in 2 months time.

t.muller@lse.ac.uk

Problem description:
If I'm working on a spreadsheet and need input from my co-workers on the same spreadsheet, I'd start to send the sheet around (probably via Email if we worked on excel offline). Unfortunately, we tend to quickly lose an overview of the different versions in the chain, and it sometimes even happens that some of us are mistakenly working on an old version. As soon as we managed to gather the input from everyone,  we struggle to get to the root of newly introduced bugs and understand and approve all changes made.

Comment: What problem? You have X version, downloaded and paid for. Then a new version comes out and you download that. It’s called updating and can set to manual or automatic.

Comment: "What I meant is the following: "  What following??

Comment: If I'm working on a spreadsheet and need input from my co-workers on the same spreadsheet I'd start to send the sheet around (if we work on excel offline). Hereby, I'm oftentimes facing the problem that we look overview about which one is the newest version + it is difficult for me to find bugs and truly understand who changed what as soon as the spreadsheet comes back to me in the chain.

Comment: The case of the disappearing comments...

Comment: additionally, we have to coordinate carefully to make sure no one’s work is overwritten.

Comment: Don't add info in comments - they can disappear (as some have already...) add the info to the original question by using the edit functionality.

Comment: haha yes sorry! first-time StackOverflow user lol